# How can I tell how much bounty a wanted target is worth without killing them?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Right now, I only seem to be able to find out how much bounty a Wanted man was worth after I kill him and it flashes in large letters on the screen that I've just earned an X credit bounty.

Sometimes, it's a pitiful amount hardly commensurate with the effort it took to kill them. Is there any way to find out how much bounty a target is worth before killing them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your Contacts tab on the left panel of your ship. If they show up as wanted, it'll show the amount in their entry in the Contacts tab.

It's worth mentioning that this won't show *all* of their bounties until you scan them with a Kill Warrant Scanner, so if they have bounties from other systems as well, you won't be eligible for those without the scan.

Comment: Update to this answer: A game balance change in November 2020 increased bounty payouts by between 4-10 times **without changing the amount displayed in the contacts** or the kill notification. After the bounty is awarded, the true amount will be shown in the bounty vouchers in the transactions tab.